# Getting value of selected right click menu item in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, contextmenu, right-click

Is there any method to get value of selected right clicked menu item or Context Menu Item. 
The context menu item here in consideration is default context menu when user presses right click in browser inside webpage. Provided solutions available on web are only for custom context menus. 
Is there any way to get value of selected menu item for context menu which comes default with firefox and chrome.
Here is the image for reference

[image]

Comment: The answer is "not possible"

Comment: @mplungjan can you briefly explain why it is not possible?

Comment: You do not have access to the "chrome" (surroundings)of the browser from script. Then you could conceivably access the tab titles or possibly click save for the user. It would be a security risk